# Statistics and Probability- Cumulative Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are $10,000$ people in front of you in line at the airport. Each person takes $\text{Exp}(1/3)$ minutes to be served once they get to the front of the line. Approximate the probability that you get to the front of the line in less than $29,000$ minutes.

I am not sure how to solve this question. Do I have to use some distribution function? Can I get some hints. My options are:

a) $\phi(-\frac{10}{3})$

b) $\phi(-\frac{11}{3})$

Comment: You might try the central limit theorem

Comment: Can you calculate the mean and variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer (a) is correct

This because the CLT states that

$$\frac{\sum_i X_i-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sim \Phi$$

The $\Phi$ has to be a capital letter because it is a CDF